# OpenVPN with subnets and other permission for each of them

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, subnet

Is it possible to configure openVPN network in topology subnet to split network for subnets and add other behavior for each subnets regarding to possibility to communicate for each clients e.g. in some subnets i want to allow clients to communicate each other but in other just disallow?